# Narashimha as "Yoga Narashimha"

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, alwar, narasimha, dhyana

I have seen many Divya Desams (Divya Desam or Vaishnava Divya Desam is one of the 108 Vishnu and Lakshmi temples that is mentioned in the works of the Alvars) where lord Narashimha is mainly in Dhyana(meditation), Why is that Narashimha is always in Dhyana(meditation) unlike other Gods?